# How to release code that depends on an unmerged branch

Tags: python, git, branch, open-source

I am outlining the dependencies in the documentation for a small open source package I am working on. My package depends on an unmerged branch of scipy that has some special functions that I need. To install it myself, I just cloned this unmerged branch and installed it from source (everything works fine).

I am just asking about the proper etiquette for this situation. I want to give proper credit to this person who added these unmerged changes. I am new to open source development so any advice is helpful.

Comment: Do you want to release your application or the scipy branch?

Comment: fwiw, http://opensource.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I just want to release my application

Answer (score 0):

If you want to release your application (or make a snapshot) with a library stored in a repository (GitHub) you can use `dependency_links` to point to the repository.

Take a look at this: https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#dependencies-that-aren-t-in-pypi

Example:

```
setup(
    ...
    dependency_links=[
        "http://peak.telecommunity.com/snapshots/"
    ],
)
```